# How to get a Router Gateway?

Tags: delphi, ip, router

I am using a routine to gather the internal IP addresses and it works well when there is only one IP address. But, on my laptop, it has VMWare Player installed and it has two Virtual Adapters and these IPs come up in the list.

192.168.41.7 - 192.168.5.4 - 192.168.1.10

The first two are VMWare's Virtual adapters. I know the router Gateway is 192.168.1.1. So, if I can programmatically read the routers Gateway I can then match the third segment of the IP to know which one I am after.

I found some links to an MS site for getting adapter info, but I am looking for some code snippets as I have no idea where to start with the MS details.

Can someone please assist or point me at some sites.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post one of the links to the MS site that you found helpful so that we know what you're already looking at?

Comment: You have an IP address for each connected network adapter installed. With VMWare you get at least two more (one for bridged VMs and one form NAT'ed ones). I remember playing with WMI to get that kind of information from Windows years ago, but I don't have access to that code anymore.

Comment: If you want to call Win API functions, you are expected to be able to read and understand the documentation. It won't help you for others to do all the work for you because you aren't prepared to learn how to use this documentation. You will need to adjust your expectations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I read it, I understood what I read, but converting from another language is beyond my skill at the moment. I can't see the sense in learning several languages at the same time. Surely it is better to master one and then move to another. I am learning a lot right now and I do have other school work to contend with. Also with programming so far, I am finding it easier to understand by seeing what others do. Sorry I will not ask you anything else, but I see Mr. Lebeau has kindly translated the code.

Comment: If you want to be able to do Win32 programming, then you simply have to be able to read C. That's all. You don't need to write it. You don't even really need to understand the operators. All you need to do is understand how types are declared. Not very much to it. But if you don't want to learn, that's obviously your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) and [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) report local IPs and Gateways for each network adapter.  For example:

```
uses
  ..., IpTypes, IpHlpApi;

  procedure GetLocalAddressesByAdaptersAddresses;
  var
    Ret: DWORD;
    BufLen: ULONG;
    Adapter, Adapters: PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES;
    UnicastAddr: PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS;
    Gateway: PIP_ADAPTER_GATEWAY_ADDRESS;
    IPAddr: string;
  begin
    // MSDN says:
    // The recommended method of calling the GetAdaptersAddresses function is
    // to pre-allocate a 15KB working buffer pointed to by the AdapterAddresses
    // parameter. On typical computers, this dramatically reduces the chances
    // that the GetAdaptersAddresses function returns ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW,
    // which would require calling GetAdaptersAddresses function multiple times.

    BufLen := 1024*15;
    GetMem(Adapters, BufLen);
    try
      repeat
        // TODO: include GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_ALL_INTERFACES on Vista+?
        Ret := GetAdaptersAddresses(PF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST or GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST or GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER or GAA_FLAG_SKIP_FRIENDLY_NAME or GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS, nil, Adapters, BufLen);
        case Ret of
          ERROR_SUCCESS:
          begin
            // Windows CE versions earlier than 4.1 may return ERROR_SUCCESS and
            // BufLen=0 if no adapter info is available, instead of returning
            // ERROR_NO_DATA as documented...
            if BufLen = 0 then begin
              Exit;
            end;
            Break;
          end;
          ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED:
          begin
            Result := False;
            Exit;
          end;
          ERROR_NO_DATA,
          ERROR_ADDRESS_NOT_ASSOCIATED:
            Exit;
          ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
            ReallocMem(Adapters, BufLen);
        else
          RaiseLastError(Ret);
        end;
      until False;

      if Ret = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
        Adapter := Adapters;
        repeat
          if (Adapter.IfType <> IF_TYPE_SOFTWARE_LOOPBACK) and
            ((Adapter.Flags and IP_ADAPTER_RECEIVE_ONLY) = 0) then
          begin
            UnicastAddr := Adapter^.FirstUnicastAddress;
            while UnicastAddr <> nil do
            begin
              if UnicastAddr^.DadState = IpDadStatePreferred then
              begin
                case UnicastAddr^.Address.lpSockaddr.sin_family of
                  AF_INET: begin
                    // use PSockAddrIn(UnicastAddr^.Address.lpSockaddr)^.sin_addr as needed...
                  end;
                  AF_INET6: begin
                    // use PSockAddrIn6(UnicastAddr^.Address.lpSockaddr)^.sin6_addr as needed...
                  end;
                end;
              end;
              UnicastAddr := UnicastAddr^.Next;
            end;
            Gateway := Adapter^.FirstGatewayAddress;
            while Gateway <> nil do
            begin
              case Gateway^.Address.lpSockaddr.sin_family of
                AF_INET: begin
                  // use PSockAddrIn(Gateway^.Address.lpSockaddr)^.sin_addr as needed...
                end;
                AF_INET6: begin
                  // use PSockAddrIn6(Gateway^.Address.lpSockaddr)^.sin6_addr as needed...
                end;
              end;
              Gateway := Gateway^.Next;
            end;
          end;
          Adapter := Adapter^.Next;
        until Adapter = nil;
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Adapters);
    end;
  end;

  procedure GetLocalAddressesByAdaptersInfo;
  var
    Ret: DWORD;
    BufLen: ULONG;
    Adapter, Adapters: PIP_ADAPTER_INFO;
    IPAddr, Gateway: PIP_ADDR_STRING;
  begin
    BufLen := 1024*15;
    GetMem(Adapters, BufLen);
    try
      repeat
        Ret := GetAdaptersInfo(Adapters, BufLen);
        case Ret of
          ERROR_SUCCESS:
          begin
            // Windows CE versions earlier than 4.1 may return ERROR_SUCCESS and
            // BufLen=0 if no adapter info is available, instead of returning
            // ERROR_NO_DATA as documented...
            if BufLen = 0 then begin
              Exit;
            end;
            Break;
          end;
          ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED,
          ERROR_NO_DATA:
            Exit;
          ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
            ReallocMem(Adapters, BufLen);
        else
          RaiseLastOSError(Ret);
        end;
      until False;

      if Ret = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
        Adapter := Adapters;
        repeat
          IPAddr := @(Adapter^.IpAddressList);
          repeat
            // use IPAddr^.IpAddress.S as needed...
            IPAddr := IPAddr^.Next;
          until IPAddr = nil;
          Gateway := @(Adapter^.GatewayList);
          repeat
            // use Gateway^.IpAddress.S as needed...
            Gateway := Gateway^.Next;
          until Gateway = nil;
          Adapter := Adapter^.Next;
        until Adapter = nil;
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Adapters);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the ones I already found, but they are not in Delphi. I am 14 and been programming 2 months so other languages will have to wait for now. That stuff looks like tangled twizzlers to me.

Comment: I added Delphi examples for you.

Comment: Thank you **very much,** I will also use it to compare the two languages so I can start understanding the code on the MS site.